# Using lxml to parse a file with repeated elements

Tags: lxml

I am trying to process a GDML file which is not what I would call a flat structure.

Rather than

```
   <materials>
   <define>
   <solids>
   <structure>
```

With single elements

I am now trying to process a file with

```
    <materials>
    <define>
    <solids>
    <define>
    <solids>
    <define>
    <solids>
    <structure>`
```

And the solids use the same names for defines which are in the preceeding define definition.
Can one process this sort of structure with lxml? If yes what is the best approach.

Need advice on how to tackle this situation as current implementation only finds the last define information.

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is. What is your current implementation? Please show us actual XML samples.

Comment: Consider to post well-formed minimal samples if you want to allow us to understand the structure of an XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Is https://gdml.web.cern.ch/GDML/gdmlexample.html an example? Then it seems you could use XSLT and keys on e.g. `<xsl:key name="material" match="material" use="@name"/>` and then when processing e.g. `<structure><volume><materialref ref="Air"/>...` you can use e.g. `key('material', materialref/@ref)` to find the referenced `material` element.